# Scala. List of futures. Item by item execution

Tags: scala, future

I have a List of some entities. They can be nested each to other. For example:

```
case class Entity(id: Long, parentId: Long)

val list = List(
    Entity(1,0),
    Entity(2,1),
    Entity(3,2),
    Entity(4,1),
    Entity(5,0)
)
```

My goal - is to insert each of them in database. My service:

```
val listOfFutures = list map createEntity // createEntity - my method,
                                          // which inserts entity in database.
                                          // returns Future[Entity]
Future.sequence( list ) map { _ => println("Ok!") }
```

The problem - is constraints. I get error:

> Create failed. No such parent 1 entity exists.

I think, the reason - is parallel execution of `createEntity` method. How to make this futures to be step by step executed?

**P.S.** Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Comment: Unlike it's name,  `Future.sequence` doesn't execute `Future` sequentially, but from a `Seq`, e.g. not awaiting the `Future` #1 complete before executing the second.

Comment: http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/execute-scala-futures-in-serial-one-after-the-other-non-blocking

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thank you, but I think, this code is awful for command develop.

Comment: There is no other way if you need each `Future` to "wait for" the previous one